# How do I solve given only 1 of 3 probability values

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am given 3 disjoint events A, B, and C. And the following expression to solve when the P(A) = 2/5.

$P(A \cup ( B^c \cup C^c)^c )$

From De Morgen's Law:

I can transform it to $P(A \cup (B \cup C))$ and since A, B, and C are disjoint I can rewrite it to $P(A) + P(B) + P(C)$.

How do I go about solving $P(A \cup ( B^c \cup C^c)^c )$ with only 1 of the 3 variables.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you did not apply De Morgan's laws correctly. They give

$$(B^{c} \cup C^{c})^{c}=((B^{c})^{c} \cap (C^{c})^{c})=(B \cap C)\quad [\text{De Morgan}]$$

And hence

$$P(A \cup (B^c \cup C^c)^c ) = P(A \cup (B \cap C)) = P(A) + P(B \cap C) = P(A)$$

Where we used the disjointness of the events

Comment: Thanks of the feedback. I realize I wrote De Morgan wrong. But, so are you saying that $P(A \cup  (B^c \cup C^c))$ = P(A) = 2/5?

Comment: Yes! Since the events are mutually disjoint we have that $B \cap C = \emptyset$ end hence $P(A \cup (B^c \cup C^c)^c) = P(A) + P(\emptyset) = P(A) = 2/5$

Comment: Oh man, thats right. I read "disjoint" but really didn't give sufficient thought to what that meant. Thank you very much for your feedback.